# Does anyone know why intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with native c++ is soooo slow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I had update 1 previously and it was near perfect, since update 2 they switched from the old sdf files to a db file claiming the performance is better. The performance is definitely not better, there is constant parsing and it takes anywhere from 10 to 15 seconds to bring up intellisense suggestions. Does anyone know of any fixes for this?

Comment: That is not a common complaint.  Pay attention to what happens to the yourproject.vc.db file .  It can only take this long if it recreates it from scratch instead of using the version that was left on the disk after you last had the project opened.

Comment: If you have uninstalled the SQL Server that comes with Visual Studio, reinstall it

Comment: @otc the new browsing database format is SQLite not SQL Server.

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in update 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch back to the old database by going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Browsing/Navigation -> Enable New Database Engine -> False.

I sometimes delete the browsing database files to force fresh ones to be built in case something has gone wrong with them internally as does seem to happen from time to time in my experience. My browsing database got jammed when I moved to the new database format but was fine after I deleted all traces of it and let it start afresh.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this, and it was able to look up some simple ones in my large solution quickly enough, but it was also matching text strings in comments. I tried a less simple one and it was taking forever, during which I tried setting it back, and then it seemed to just be broken/stuck. I'm trying to exit VS now, and it's locking up trying to exit with a Find All References stuck in progress.